# Scrapy: Ignoring response 403

Tags: python, heroku, scrapy

I am trying to launch a spider on an [Epyco (Heroku app)](http://epico.herokuapp.com), but I get a 403 error.How I can prevent this error? What am I doing wrong?

```
INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://www.ratemds.com/best-doctors/?specialty=acupuncturist>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

spider:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import scrapy

class Ratemds(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ratemds'
    allowed_domains = ['ratemds.com']

    custom_settings = {
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like     Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.50747 OPRGX/60.0.3255.50747',
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2.5, 
    }

def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request('https://www.ratemds.com/best-doctors/?specialty=acupuncturist', callback=self.profile_link)

def profile_link(self, response):
    for a in response.css('.search-item-doctor-link'):
        yield response.follow(a, callback=self.profile)

def profile(self, response):
    item =  {
            'url': response.request.url,
            'Image': response.css('.doctor-profile-image::attr(src)').get(),
            'First_and_Last_Name': response.css('h1::text').get(),
            'Position': response.css('.col-sm-6 .search-item-info~ .search-item-info+ .search-item-info span::text').getall(),
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(Ratemds)
    process.start()
```

Comment: You can set `handle_httpstatus_list = [403]` in spider attribute and handle this in callback on your code.

Comment: Also 403 means unauthorized request so you can check why your request is considered as unauthorized. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html#reproducing-requests